# new and reallocating memory

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator, realloc

`new[]` doesn't support change the size of allocated memory, does it?

For example, I allocated memory with `new[]` for buffer (array of char) and I want to get the additional memory.

Should I use `malloc`/`realloc` instead in this case?

Comment: Can't you use std::string?

Comment: Do things the easy way, use vector (or string).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482941/how-do-you-realloc-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new` does not support that.

You can mimic the behavior of `realloc` manually using `new`, `delete` and `memcpy`.

By the way, you should always use the same family of methods i.e. either `malloc` / `realloc` / `free` or `new` / `delete`, and not mix `realloc` with `new` / `delete`. See for example the [FMM errors reported by Purify](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/rational/docs/v2003/purify/html/ht_m_fmm.htm).

Comment: That would be `std::copy`, not `memcpy`, unless you're sure you're only using trivially-copyable types.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can come in standard C++ without resorting to the C holdovers `malloc` and `realloc` is to use `std::vector<char>`. This can be resized at any time, and if the underlying storage gets reallocated the contents will be automatically copied.

Comment: Using std::vector<char> instead of the C-string affects the speed?

Comment: @Dmitry it shouldn't, but if this is important to you you should benchmark it. Different implementations can vary.

Comment: ok. And what's the faster, std::vector<char> or std::string you think?

Comment: @Dmitry: They do pretty much the same thing, so will be about as fast as each other. If you really need to count nanoseconds, then you'll have to time them, or analyse the generated machine code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::vector`.  You'll not have to deal with these issues.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to use malloc/realloc with new.

new will not support reallocating more memory once applied.

So a good idea would be to create a new buffer with extra memory, memcpy and delete the old buffer.
Then point to this new buffer.

Comment: And as Basilevs said, in C++ Vector is always better choics because it has been implemented to automatically resize if need arises.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. It can be resized.